# Sharp drop in Alexa rankings in 2Q 2011?

Tags: discussion, statistics

Both Stack Overflow and [The Hyphenated Site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts-Exchange) (EE) sites are affected, EE in fact goes way down and Super User also notices a drop after reaching a record in the same time while Stack Overflow goes sharply down.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What happened? A new player on the market?

http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com

Comment: http://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com?country=US

Comment: I swore there was a blog post about this, but now I can't find it

Comment: I think you're overestimating the decline of Super User, especially given that its traffic still is higher than most of the previous months, I would only be worried if it kept declining, which doesn't seem to happen. Oh and stop using Alexa, Stack Exchange is a verified Quantcast client

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just went to Hacker News, and [one of the top stories](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3182198) was [an article about this happening to the hyphen site](http://www.itwriting.com/blog/5063-the-power-of-google-how-the-panda-update-hit-experts-exchange.html). How convenient. The author observed that...

> That vertical line is around April 2011, which is when Google rolled out its ["High Quality Sites Algorithm"](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/04/high-quality-sites-algorithm-goes.html).

This correlates well with the drops for the hyphen site and Stack Overflow, but doesn't match up with Super User's.

Comment: There have been several Panda updates and SU's might align with one of the others, however it seems to have picked up its steam again since the first changes